# Transit visa Nigeria and India via Germany

Tags: transit-visas, schengen-visas

I'm an Indian citizen who is living in Lagos, Nigeria. I have an Indian passport and a Nigerian residence permit. I'm planning to go for the following trip. All my flights will be from Lufthansa and will have a stopover in Frankfurt or Munich.

> Leg 1: Lagos, Nigeria -> (Frankfurt) -> London, UK (Possess single entry tourist visa for UK)
>
> Leg 2: London, UK -> (Munich) -> New Delhi, India
>
> Leg 3: New Delhi, India -> (Frankfurt) -> Lagos, Nigeria

Leg 1 seems fine because my destination is London and I hold a visa for it. I however unsure of whether I'll require a transit visa for leg 2 and leg 3.

The lufthansa page tells me

> Indian nationals can Transit without Visa via FRA or MUC if holding a valid visa for the destination and a valid Visa for any of the following countries.
>
> Bulgaria, Canada, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan, Liechtenstein, Romania, UK and USA (the approval notice I-797 is not valid document for visa free airport transit).

I do hold a multiple entry tourist visa to the US that is valid during this travel period. However, I'm unsure of whether it is sufficient as none of my legs have a US destination.